# WebView is exiting instead of going back

Tags: android, webview

As an example, here used google as the website. When we click on any link and try to go back by hitting back button, it not calling goBack() but exiting. Back button in websites also not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint({"setJavaScriptEnabled"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

I'm using this code for months without any error, suddenly i got issue this few days back without any modifications. I also tried by calling goBack() in onBackPressed() with if statement but still shows same issue. Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because its chrome bug : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794020

This has been fixed in M64. You can find a public release calendar here [1]. This is just an approximate schedule, but we aim to be close to the public schedule.

According to the schedule, M64 will go to stable January 23rd.

While M64 is currently in beta, we have not yet made a beta release with the fix. I do not have information for when such a beta release will go out (but it will be sooner than Jan 23rd).

[1] https://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar